# Adding authentication HTTP header to NativeScript Image

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I’m utilising HttpInterceptor to add the authenticator header with token for my general HTTP requests however this doesn’t seem to cover Image requests so

```
<Image src="https://example.net/image.png"></Image>
```

Never displays as not authenticated. I assume this is due to Image using the older version of the Http client. Is there an easy way to add the header without having to separately load each resource. Any modules or extending Image class would be good.

Comment: IMHO - When you request image like that , it doesn't go through interceptors. One option is to add the auth header to query string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure query string is supported and wouldn't feel 100% comfortable putting there. I would also have to write the URL on a 401 response which could be trickier.

Comment: I was talking about `src="https://example.net/image.png?a=1"`. this is supported. also it's not a thing that a person with wireshark wouldn't see , just as much as the headers you're trying to put

Comment: Unfortunately it would be recorded in logs and the like. I've checked and can't find any mention of it in Office365 oAuth2 version 1 implementation unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you can bind your `src` property to your view model, use `http` module to download the image and once done assign the local cached path to your view model and image will be notified and loaded.

If you are planning to reuse often, try expending `Image` to build a custom component that allows header.

**Update:** [Simple example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=97oYn5)

Comment: Thanks Manjo. As per question I'm looking for examples of extending the class and avoiding having to manually load each resource. I was hoping that someone may have already tackled this by simply overriding a function.

Comment: @BenMorris [Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=97oYn5) you go.

**Note:** By handling the remote images ourselves using `ImageSource.fromUrl` we loose features like decoded width and height, caching etc., in Android. This example can be improved further by implementing caching and decoding.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj I need to catch the 401s too but it's a good start for me. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the example above:

```
import { fromBase64, fromNativeSource } from "tns-core-modules/image-source";
import { Cache } from "tns-core-modules/ui/image-cache";
import { Image } from "tns-core-modules/ui/image";
import * as Sqlite from 'nativescript-sqlite';

const cache = new Cache();
const sqlite = new Sqlite('cache.sqlite', {
    multithreading: !!Sqlite.HAS_COMMERCIAL,
    migrate: true
})
    .then(async db => {
        await db.execSQL(`
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
            image_cache (
                url TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
                base_64 TEXT NOT NULL,
                timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
            )
        `);
        console.log('Table created');
        return db;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.error('Table not created', e);
        throw e;
    });

function setToDbCache (url, imageSource) {
    return sqlite
        .then(db => {
            return db.execSQL('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO image_cache (url, base_64) VALUES(?, ?)', [url, imageSource.toBase64String()]);
        }, () => 0);
}
function getFromDbCache (url) {
    return sqlite
        .then(async db => {
            let res = await db.get('SELECT base_64 FROM image_cache WHERE url = ?', [url]);
            if (res.length) {
                return fromBase64(res[0]);
            }
            return null;
        })
        .catch(() => null);
}

export default class RemoteImage extends Image {
    _createImageSourceFromSrc(url) {
        // look into image-cache if exists
        const image = cache.get(url);
        if (image) {
            this.imageSource = fromNativeSource(image);
        } else {
            this.imageSource = null;
            this.isLoading = true;
            // look into sqlite-cache if exists
            getFromDbCache(url)
                .then(image => {
                    if (image) {
                        this.imageSource = image;
                        this.isLoading = false;
                        // write it in image-cache
                        // TODO: iOS
                        cache.set(url, image.android);
                    } else {
                        // request image (writes in cache automatically)
                        cache
                            .push({
                                key: url,
                                url: url,
                                completed: (image, key) => {
                                    if (url === key) {
                                        this.imageSource = fromNativeSource(image);
                                        this.isLoading = false;
                                        // write it in sqlite-cache too
                                        setToDbCache(url, this.imageSource);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

There I use the standard [NS `image-cache`](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/image-cache) combined with the [sqlite plugin](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-sqlite)